# C# How to call of the Controls from one Form to the other

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
foreach (var solid in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    if (this.Location.X + this.Width / 2 >= solid.Location.X - solid.Width / 2)
        this.RightM = false;

    if (this.Location.X - this.Width / 2 >= solid.Location.X + solid.Width / 2)
         this.LeftM = false;

    if (this.Location.Y - this.Height / 2 <= solid.Location.Y + solid.Height / 2)
    {
        this.JumpB = false;
        this.ForceJump = 9;
    }

    if (this.Location.Y + this.Height / 2 >= solid.Location.Y - solid.Height / 2)
         this.JumpB = false;
    else
        this.Top -= ForceJump;
}
```

This code is in my class "Player", of course that call won't work because it's `this.Controls`... etc. So how do i do this?

Comment: So other people might be able to infer your framework from the context but I cannot. What is a `PictureBox`? What kind of form? Is this WPF, Winforms, something else entirely?

Comment: Winforms i want to make Player solid to all of objects(for example pictureboxes),so when player touch some of then(some of pictureboxes),player stop moving,so how to i do that in foreach,how to call all of the pictureboxes created in other forms.

Comment: Share more code. It is quite unclear **what those "other forms" would be?** did you design an MDI game, with windows all over the place? or is it rather a canvas where multiple picture boxes move around and one of them is the player?

Comment: I tried to do that.(My level is called "Level1", its a winform and i tried it like this)
foreach(var solid in Level1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
but there is a error

Comment: yes one of then is a player

Comment: Level1 tut = new Level1l();
            foreach (var solid in tut.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()),

Comment: I tried that but the player stil go it doest stop

Comment: I think you are on the right track, maybe its just a small thing, but it will be impossible for people here to help you when they cannot understand and reproduce the actual problem. if there is an error, post information about it (which line, which exception, call stack). if you find unexpected behavior, post all code needed to reproduce the problem, no more, no less (a minimal complete example). I am missing in particular the logic where you move based on the boolean value of `RightM` / `LeftM`.

Comment: if (this.LeftM)
            {
                this.RightM = false;
                this.Left -= 3;
            }

            if (this.RightM)
            {
                this.LeftM = false;
                this.Left += 3;
            }

            if (this.JumpB)
            {
                this.Top -= ForceJump;
                ForceJump--;
            }

Comment: to short you LeftM is LeftMove so when it is enabled player move to left, RightM is just for right and JumpB is for jump.

Comment: "All forms" does not mean much, if you are using the application framework (legacy) from VB.NET you can get all the forms from the `My` namespace, if not, then you should keep a reference to all your forms somewhere (add/remove when needed) to loop and do your work.

Comment: I made Timer in class (Timer MoveTimer = new Timer();)
and when it tick the player move.
thoose booleans are also part of the class.
public bool RightM;
        public bool LeftM;
        public bool JumpB;
        public int ForceJump;
but the thing is i just want to make all of the pictureboxes called in that foreach
(in all forms etc...)

Comment: user4388177 i dont need the count of the pictureboxes i want to know when player touched any picturebox
i tried by using foreach

Comment: @VukUskokovic Count/Actions/Changing their name to Fluffy/Whatever you need to do on it you still need a reference to the forms. Only other option is this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2009/08/17/gc-helper-for-obtaining-live-instances-of-a-type-or-how-i-implemented-gcgetaliveinstancesoflttgt/ but definitely not for production code.

Comment: Pass all the forms to it and then traverse each form and call the above method and pass the form to it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thank you <3